# Scrape Href python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, href, screen-scraping

Looking to scrape citynames from a certain site. This is the relevant code i've written so far, with the text stored in a variable. However, I need to place all the citynames in a list, which does not seem to work for me. Here is the HTML:

```
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptrContinents_ctl00_rptrRows_ctl00_lnkBunker" href="PortDetails.aspx?ElementID=ffd65ee0-93ea-4195-b1ba-a69c8b1908c5">Amsterdam</a>
```

And this is my code:
    names = row.find_all('th')

```
column_1 = col[0].string.strip()
Ifo380.append(column_1)
column_2 = col[3].string.strip()
Ifo180.append(column_2)
column_3 = col[6].string.strip()
Mdo.append(column_3)
column_4 = col[9].string.strip()
Mgo.append(column_4)

for port in names:
name= item.contents.find_all("a").string
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: where's the complete content? and what are column_x for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list comprehension` :

```
>>> html = '<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptrContinents_ctl00_rptrRows_ctl00_lnkBunker" href="PortDetails.aspx?ElementID=ffd65ee0-93ea-4195-b1ba-a69c8b1908c5">Amsterdam</a>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> citynames = [names.text for names in soup.find_all('a')]
['Amsterdam']
```

Answer (score 0):

Say that your html content was stored as:

```
html_cont = '<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptrContinents_ctl00_rptrRows_ctl00_lnkBunker" href="PortDetails.aspx?ElementID=ffd65ee0-93ea-4195-b1ba-a69c8b1908c5">Amsterdam</a>'
```

Then you could parse it and add the cities to the list as:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_cont, "lxml")

city_names = []
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    city_names.append(link.text)
```